# Using Recursion in java

Tags: java

I'm working on the Conway's game of life program. I have the first two generations of cells printed out, but I can not get anymore printed. So I decided to use recursion so multiple batches of cells can be printed. My NewCells method creates the second generation. I thought that If I were to repeat said method by returning NewCells(c) instead of c, It would print out different results, but it prints out the same batch of cells over and over again.

```
public class Life {

public static boolean[][] NewCells(boolean[][] c)
{
    int N = 5;
    int o=0;
    int p=0;
    int livecnt = 0; //keeps track of the alive cells surrounding cell
    int store = 0; //amount of surrounding cells for each individual cell
    int livestore[] = new int[N*N];


     System.out.println("Next Generation");
     // Checks for the amount of "*" surrounding (o,p)

      for (o=0; o < N; o++)
      { 
         for (p=0; p<N; p++)
         {
             for (int k=(o-1); k <= o+1; k++)
             {

                 for (int l =(p-1); l <=p+1; l++)
                 {
                     if ( k >= 0 && k < N && l >= 0 && l < N) //for the border indexes.
                     { 

                         if (!(k== o && l==p)) //so livecnt won't include the index being checked.
                         {
                             if (c[k][l] == true)
                             {
                                livecnt++;
                             }
                    }

                 }

                 }
             }
             livestore[store]= livecnt;
             livecnt = 0;
             store++;
         }
      }


      //Prints the next batch of cells
      int counter= 0;
      for (int i2 = 0; i2 <N; i2++)
      {
          for (int j2 = 0; j2 < N; j2++)
          {

          if (c[i2][j2] == false)
                 {
                     if (livestore[counter] ==3)
                     {
                        c[i2][j2]=true;
                         System.out.print("* ");
                     }
                     else
                    System.out.print("- ");
                 }

              else if (c[i2][j2] == true)
                 {
                     if (livestore[counter] ==1)
                     {
                        c[i2][j2]= false;
                        System.out.print("- ");
                     }
                     else if (livestore[counter] >3)
                     {
                         c[i2][j2]= false;
                         System.out.print("- ");
                     } 

                     else
                         System.out.print("* ");
                 }
                 counter++;
          }
          System.out.println();
      }

    return NewCell(c);  
}
/*************************************************************************************************************************************************/
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = 5;
    boolean[][] b = new boolean[N][N];
    double cellmaker = Math.random();

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;


    int o=0;
    int p=0;
    int livecnt = 0; //keeps track of the alive cells surrounding cell
    int store = 0; //amount of surrounding cells for each individual cell
    int livestore[] = new int[N*N];


     System.out.println("First Generation:");
     // Makes the first batch of cells
     for ( i = 0; i < N ; i++)
     {

         for ( j = 0; j< N; j++)
         {
              cellmaker = Math.random();


             if (cellmaker > 0.5) // * = alive; - = dead
             {
                 b[i][j]=true;

                 System.out.print( "* ");

             }


             if (cellmaker < 0.5)
            { b[i][j] = false;


             System.out.print("- ");

            }

         }
         System.out.println();

     }       


     boolean[][] newcells = new boolean[N][N];
     newcells = NewCells(b);

}

}
```

Comment: Where is your recursion call?

Comment: `PearsonArtPhoto` is right. There is not recursion call. As a rule of thumb, finish with a question the next time. Just to make sure you know what is missing, and to avoid misunderstandings while others read the questions and answer them.

Comment: whoops. Where it says return c, it's supposed to be return NewCell(c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think recursion is a good idea for this application. It leads to a StackOverflowError because each generation pushes another call stack frame. Recursion, as this program uses it, has no advantage over iteration.

Instead, put the main method call to NewCells in a loop. That way, you can run as many iterations as you like, regardless of stack size.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `NewCell` from within `NewCell`, which is how recursion works.

I'm assuming it's not a typo in your question, but rather a lack of understanding of what it is and how it works, I recommend some reading on [recursion in Java](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=151).

After you understand the basics, come back here for more help!

Comment: It was a typo. It was supposed to be return NewCell(c) instead of return c.